# php code to link login/registration page to database

Tags: php

I am new into programming. I have written a good HTML page,login page and register page,but how can it start working? That is to connect to a database(I don't have a data base) might want to use Google drive. Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code you have written.

Comment: Start reading about php: http://www.php.net/ in combination with mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side technology for connecting to database. There are many server side languages like php/java/asp/python etc. For database you can use mysql/oracle/mysqlserver. You can go for php with mysql. Links that might be useful to you.

1. https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp for php
2. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp for mysql

Comment: Am grateful. But how do I redirect members to their dashboard with the details they supplied during registration?

Comment: @hacklord you have to send the details to the server side script and then you can either store them in session and show on the dashboard or you can store them in database and retrieve and show on the dashboard. For that you have to create a dashboard page and for redirection you have to use the redirect functions of the server side language you are using.